# Extending accessor and mutators in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to develop a small application in `Laravel 5.5` where I've made an `abstract model` which is extending `Laravel eloquent model` something like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AbstractModel extends Model
{


}
```

Now just for general convention I'm setting a database connection for this model:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AbstractModel extends Model
{
    /**
     *  Defining connection for database
     *
     * @var string
     **/
    protected $connection='mysql';

}
```

And I created my own model which extends this `abstract class`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Posts extends AbstractModel
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'unique_id', 'title', 'contents'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'id'
    ];

}
```

By defining this by default we come to know that it will have a database connection of mysql, similarly `fillable` are defined for mass assignment. In similar way I want to make one `encrypt` variable which will `encrypt` and `decrypt` the data from the database so for this I added `accessor` and `mutator` to my `encrypt variable` inside my model:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Posts extends AbstractModel
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The attributes that will have encryption.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $encryption = ['unique_id', 'title', 'contents'];

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'unique_id', 'title', 'contents'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'id'
    ];

}
```

and configured it back in my `abstract model`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AbstractModel extends Model
{
    /**
     *  Defining connection for database
     *
     * @var string
     **/
    protected $connection='mysql';

    /**
     *  Defining encryption
     *
     * @var array
     **/
    protected $encryption = [];

    public function setAttributes()
    {
        foreach ($this->encryption as $attributes)
        {
            $this->attributes[$attributes] = Crypt::encryptString($this->attributes[$attributes]);
        }
    }

    public function getAttributes()
    {
        foreach ($this->encryption as $attributes)
        {
            $this->attributes[$attributes] = Crypt::decryptString($this->attributes[$attributes]);
        }
    }
}
```

I think my approach is wrong as there is no encryption or decryption done on these attributes, I can see the data sent to create rows is stored in database without any encryption and in same way retrieved also.

More over I would like to have a use case where I'm encrypting these fields also their attribute accessor or mutator is called inside their own model for example:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Posts extends AbstractModel
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The attributes that will have encryption.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $encryption = ['unique_id', 'title', 'contents'];

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'unique_id', 'title', 'contents'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'id'
    ];

    public function setTitleAttributes($value)
    {
        return ucfirst($value);
    }

    public function getTitleAttributes($value)
    {
        return ucfirst($value)
    }

}
```

Any feedback comments are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the Eloquent model has `setAttribute()` & `getAttribute()` methods not `setAttributes()` and `getAttributes()`.

Secondly, for this kind of situation. I'd rather use the [Eloquent's event](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events). Because the `setAttribute()` or `getAttribute()` methods will only be fired when you access the attribute dynamically like: `$post->title`.

You can encrypt the attributes on `saving` event. And decrypt it back using `retrieved` event.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

abstract class AbstractModel extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql';

    protected $encryption = [];

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        // When being retrieved, decrypt the attributes.
        static::retrieved(function ($instance) {
            foreach ($instance->encryption as $encryptedKey) {
                $instance->attributes[$encryptedKey] = Crypt::decryptString($instance->attributes[$encryptedKey]);
            }
        });

        // When saving (could be create or update) the modal, encrypt the attributes.
        static::saving(function ($instance) {
            foreach ($instance->encryption as $encryptedKey) {
                $instance->attributes[$encryptedKey] = Crypt::encryptString($instance->attributes[$encryptedKey]);
            }
        });

        // Once it's saved, decrypt it back so it's still readble.
        static::saved(function ($instance) {
            foreach ($instance->encryption as $encryptedKey) {
                $instance->attributes[$encryptedKey] = Crypt::decryptString($instance->attributes[$encryptedKey]);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When you decided to use this approach, don't override both the `setAttribute()` & `getAttribute()` methods. Since it will most likely to double encrypt/decrypt the attributes.

Also, it supposed to be `setTitleAttribute()` and `getTitleAttribute()`—in singular form. And on the `setTitleAttribute()` you should mutate the `title` attribute; not returning the intended value. I don't see the purpose of capitalizing the `title` either since it will be encrypted anyway.

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $encryption = ['unique_id', 'title', 'contents'];

    protected $fillable = ['unique_id', 'title', 'contents'];

    // Expected to mutate the title attribute.
    public function setTitleAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['title'] = ucfirst($value);
    }

    public function getTitleAttribute($value)
    {
        return ucfirst($value);
    }
}
```

Hope this gives you some ideas.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the update, I can see all my values are getting encrypted but I'm getting error while retrieving the data `Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException with message 'The payload is invalid.'`

Comment: But when I do `$posts = App\Posts::find(3); Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::decryptString($posts->name);` in tinker I get the appropriate results.

Comment: I can't really tell what's happening. Need to see your code both on `AbstractModel` and `Post` classes.

Comment: Both of them are mentioned above in the question, I've not added anything else, in fact while testing this I've not used any accessor and mutator inside post model.

Comment: @NitishKumar I've decided to try it on my own using Laravel 5.5 with sqlite database. It's working just fine on my machine. Check the code here: https://gist.github.com/risan/99d1cf2b71c0fa754d01ad45227b4697

Comment: Hey thanks, I did a small check into my migrations I've set default length to my string to 191 which was causing problem. Your code is working like charm when I changed the defaults, Thanks a lot for help.